# Бронирование билетов в кинотеатре

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, codefirst

форумчане.

Задача: бронирование билетов в кинотеатре.
(Спроектированная схема во вложении).

Собственно вопросы:

1. с чем связать таблицу "Место"? (на один сеанс разные клиенты не должны бронировать одно и тоже место, да и один клиент не должен бронировать одно и тоже место дважды на один сеанс)
2. в какую таблицу лучше определить атрибут цена?

P.S. Пишу приложение на ASP.NET CORE используя Entity Framework (code first).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Таблицу "Залы" потеряли?

Comment: *с чем связать таблицу "Место"?* Должна существовать таблица связи (сеанс-место-цена). И таблица связи этой таблицы с таблицей Заказ (если в заказе может быть несколько мест) или ссылочное поле в таблице Заказ.

Comment: PS. Собственно то, что у тебя "Место" - это и есть недоделанная таблица связи, ибо статус бронирования есть атрибут сущности-связи конкретного места и конкретного сеанса. А таблица мест должна содержать только список мест (и, возможно, ссылку на вышеупомянутую таблицу залов).

Comment: Зал один. Количество мест постоянное.

Answer (score 0):

1. Заказ и Место объединить, т.к. в создании отдельной таблицы Место нет смысла - у Вас таблица будет пополняться регулярно и, если нет ключа уникальности по строкам (ряд+место), то и смысла в создании таблицы нет. Если такое ограничение уникальности добавить- сможете продать только одно место на один фильм - дальше ограничение уникальности сработает, и продать то же место на другой фильм не получится. Забронированные места доставать из коллекции оплаченных/забронированных заказов по признаку. Проще через LinQ
2. Цену так же в Заказ, т.к. имеет прямое отношение к заказу и в других таблицах не имеет практического смысла. Если цену выносить в отдельную таблицу(прикреплять к другой таблице) - не будет историчности данных при повышении цены.
   Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: В каждом зале ограниченное количество мест. Чтобы знать, какие места в зале вообще есть, надо хранить их где то, например, в таблице с местами. В заказе можно просто ид места указывать

Comment: Уникальность в заказе можно вешать на ид сеанса + ид места.

Comment: Зал один. Значит количество мест меняться не будет. Мне необходимо создать таблицу "Место". В таблице "Заказ" сделать уникальными КодМеста и КодСеанса?

Comment: @tym32167, что мешает добавить в Заказ ид зала со ссылкой на отдельную таблицу Зал? Необходимость таблицы Зал, к примеру, можно оправдать последующим мониторингом загруженности залов (Отчет за месяц по количеству посетителей в конкретном зале). Мониторинг загруженности конкретного места, имхо, лишнее.

Comment: @Alex, перечитайте пожалуйста ещё раз мой ответ. Если вам в рамках задания необходимо создать таблицу Место, то в вашем изначально вопросе нет смысла - делайте так, как написано в задаче. Если вы пытаетесь в оптимизацию и маштабируемость - вдумчиво прочитайте мой ответ и комментарии к нему.

Comment: Согласен. Можно добавить таблицу "Зал" и полями id и name. Таблицу "Зал" соединяем только с таблицей "Заказ"?

Comment: Таблицу "Место" в рамках задания создавать не обязательно.

Comment: @Alex, если добавляете Зал, то тогда добаляйте и Место, где Место(ид строки, ид заказа, ид зала)  будет связующей таблицей между Заказ и Зал.

Comment: @Alex, Предлагаю Вам перерисовать схему и дополнить свой вопрос. Исходя из новой схемы дополню свой ответ, если будет необходимость.

Comment: Добавил новую схему

Comment: Если добавлять таблицу с залами, то добавлять и таблицу с местами. Если хардкодить места, типа 10 рядов по 10 мест, то хардкодить и зал. Зал - это по сути аттрибут места, кроме как при выборе места он нигде не нужен. Если делать таблицу с местами, то тогда в заказе писать ид места, зал в заказе не понадобится , так как место привязано к залу.

Comment: Таблица мест поможет понять в принципе какие места есть в зале, чтобы эту информацию не хардкодить.